# Javascript: timeupdate end function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to trigger a single alert event at 15 seconds on a 45-second video file. I'm able to initiate using the function below, how would I cause the function ('the alert) to trigger only once.

```
var video = document.getElementById("media");
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
    if (e.target.currentTime == 15000);
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}, false);
```

Comment: Remove the event listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code would not work because, for every timeupdate, you cannot ensure that the current time will give you 15000(It should be 15 / 15.000 instead, right, current time used in seconds). It might not be triggered.

Instead, use setTimeout function in javascript, like this:

```
    video.play();
    var to = setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");},15000);
```

To stop the timeout, use:

```
    clearTimeout(to);
```

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Is there a way to effectively shut down the time update function once it has fire on the fist occasion. For example, where it isn't an alert but a div fade (with CSS animation).